# CSS: : Trying to get heights of sections / divs to match up....one without an img

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, cimg

I have an issue where I have a row on my site and two-thirds are a background image with text on top of it. The other third is just an image. So two sections or divs. I'm trying to get the heights to match up so whatever the height of the div on the right is, the div on the left is the same. Here's my CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvpgBz

Here's my condensed HTML:

```
<a href="#" title="" class="feature-link">
    <section id="feature1" class="feature" style="background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) ), url(https://thecleverroot.com/wp-content/uploads/header-marigold-and-mint-flower-shop.jpg ) no-repeat top center!important; background-size: cover!important;">
    <section class="feature-caption"><p class="category-link">Farm / Ranch</p><h2>Katherine Anderson </h2><p>Owner of Marigold and Mint, Seattle, WA</p><p class="read-more">Read</p></section></section>
</a>
<section class="feature-third">
    <a href="#" title="">
       <img src="https://thecleverroot.com/wp-content/uploads/cover-fall-2015.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</section>
```

And the CSS:

```
.feature { position: relative; float: left; clear: both; width: 66.66%;  color: #FFF; }
a.feature-link { text-decoration: none; }
.feature-third { position: relative; float: left; width: 33.333%; color: #FFF; overflow: hidden; display: block; }
.feature a, .feature-third a { color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; }
.feature-caption h2 { font-size: 64px; line-height: .75em; margin: .25em 0;  }
.category-link a {
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration: none;
 }
.category-link a:hover, .category-link a:focus, .category-link a:active {
     color: #fcfcfc;
 }
.read-more {
     background: #000;
     border-radius: 10px;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0 20px;
     min-width: 90px;
     height: 45px;
     line-height: 45px;
     color: #FFF;
     font-size: 18px;
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: 400;
     text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! http://codepen.io/LeeKevin/pen/QjQgJP

A summary of the changes:

1) Added a container:

HTML

```
<div class="header-container">
```

CSS

```
.header-container {
  display: flex;  
}
```

2) Added [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) styles to existing rules:

```
.feature {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
}

a.feature-link {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  width: 66.66%;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
```